# After removing event from form code page then all controls disappeared on the form designer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
  private void frmSelectCategory_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I have removed the above function and pressed <kbd>F5</kbd>, but it gave me an error and stopped debugging. All controls on the form disappeared. I put this code back and run again and it works, but when I go to coding again, there is nothing on the form.

Here is the error message:

> Error  1   'EbayForm.frmSelectCategory' does not contain a definition for 'frmSelectCategory_Load_1' and no extension method 'frmSelectCategory_Load_1' accepting a first argument of type 'EbayForm.frmSelectCategory' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Bilgehan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\tutorials\EbayForm\EbayForm\frmSelectCategory.Designer.cs   37  55  EbayForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing an event handler from your code-behind file doesn't remove the assignment from the file that's generated by the designer. You can either search for and remove it manually, or wipe out the event handler in the Properties pane.

Answer (score 0):

Open the form in the designer. Select properties and clear the event for load.

Alternatively: 
Search for all references of `frmSelectCategory_Load_1` and removed them.